# Сборка приложения андроид под MIPS

Tags: mips, android, android-ndk

Что нужно, чтобы собрать приложение на NDK под MIPS ?

Answer (score 3):

Ничего специального сейчас не требуется, надо просто в `Application.mk` добавить `APP_ABI := mips` или `APP_ABI := all` и все будет собрано.

Документация [здесь](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/mips.html)

Проверено на версиях Android NDK >=9